# Sonarqube error with angular: "Error loading java.security file"

Tags: angular, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have installed and connected to a project in .net sonarqube on my server. Now I was trying to connect it to another project but in angular. I inserted the sonar-project.properties file into the project. When in angular terminal I run "npm run sonar -X" I get the following error:

```
*INFO: SonarScanner 5.0.1.3006
INFO: Java 17.0.7 Eclipse Adoptium (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 0.056s
INFO: Final Memory: 1M/20M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.InternalError: Error loading java.security file
at java.base/java.security.Security.initialize(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.Security$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.Security$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.Security.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at java.base/javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm(Unknown Source) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.OkHttpClientFactory.systemDefaultTrustManager(OkHttpClientFactory.java:114) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.OkHttpClientFactory.create(OkHttpClientFactory.java:91)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.<init>(ServerConnection.java:52) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.create(ServerConnection.java:62) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:67)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:185)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:123)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:62)
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.*
```

This is my sonar-project.properties file:

```
*sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.login=admin
sonar.password=Imuertdmamt
sonar.projectKey=Anuglar
sonar.projectName=Angular
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=mysource
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
sonar.java.binaries= **/*.java*
```

Can anyone help me?, thanks in advance.